# What is wrong with the statement socket.sendall(message) in python 3.3?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to learn sockets in python 3.3 but have an issue sending data to the remote server. Has the command be changed in python 3.3 or am I just doing it wrong. Please find the code below so you can see the problem. Would prefer a simple splution like change s.sendall to s.send or something. If not possible no worries

```
import socket
import sys

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print("Failed to create a socket")
print("Socket created")

host = ("www.google.com")
port = 80
try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
except socket.gaierror:
    print("Hostname could not be found, exiting finding socket")
    sys.exit()
print("Ip adress of",host,"is",remote_ip)

s.connect((remote_ip, port))
print("Socket connected to",host,"on ip", remote_ip)

message = "GET / HTTP/1.1/r/n/r/n"
try:
    s.send(message)
except socket.error:
    print("Failed")
    sys.exit
print("Message send successful")

reply = s.recv(4096)
print(reply)
s.close()
```

Comment: If you get an error, please post the *entire* traceback.

Comment: What is the output / result of the code you have shown, and what output or result did you expect? (P.s. You ask about `socket.sendall()`, but your code does not contain a call to that function. )

Comment: You are not handling exceptions correctly here. You catch socket.error, but then don't exit, but rather continue the script as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you used slash where you meant to use backslash. Try this instead:

```
message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
```

Second, yes, the `send()` call did change a little. Try this:

```
s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
```